# WhatsApp crashes, shows black screen

Tags: lumia, 8.1, whatsapp

After switching to Windows Phone 8.1 many times, WhatsApp has started crashing on my Lumia 520. When that happens, all I see is a black screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 has not been officially released to the public. Also, WhatsApp is unavailable in the WP Store as they are currently fixing an issue that affects WP 8.0 GDR3

Comment: I have some problem when I click their notifications now. But tapping directly the app should work.

Comment: By "switching to 8.1 many times", do you mean you've upgraded and downgraded your phone a number of times? If so, that might have messed something up. Have you tried resetting your phone? Or simply uninstalling and reinstalling WhatsApp?

Comment: An update to WhatsApp has been released since you asked the question - does it resolve the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for the update. They know about issue and working on it:

[WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/whatsapp-and-microsoft-still-working-together-fix-missing-app)